# Capturing output from grep and cut to a variable in tcsh shell

Tags: shell, tcsh

I am trying to capture the process number from this command

```
ps ax | grep catalina
```

to a variable in tcsh shell.

So far, I am able to echo the process number to the screen using this script:

```
set pnum = `ps ax | grep catalina`
echo $pnum | cut -d' ' -f1
```

But when I try this to get the result of both the `grep` and the `cut`

```
set pnum = `ps ax | grep catalina | cut -d' ' -f1`
```

the result is an empty string.

And this sequence

```
set pnum = `ps ax | grep catalina`
set pnum = `$pnum | cut -d' ' -f1`
```

generates a `1104: Command not found.` error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you need to deconstruct your process even further (maybe  you have). To understand your problem first see what `ps ax | grep catalina` displays, THEN add the `set pnum =..` stuff.

Yes, you should be able to chain it into one pipeline, but note that if/when there are spaces at the beginning of the output, you have to increment your `-f1` to account for each space, so a 4 digit PID will require more `-f**n**` than a 6 digit PID.

Also note that to remove the `grep` line that will appear, use

```
| grep '[c]atalina'
```

AND, finally, think about what your error message `1104: Command not found.` is telling you.

That's the processID produced by `$pnum` which you have at the front of your 2nd line. Again, getting in the habit of deconstructing failing code makes it easy to see where the problems are. You can also turn on the shell debug trace with `#!/bin/tcsh -vx` as the she-bang line for your script.

---

**A possibly better solution** is to use

```
set pnum = `ps ax | awk '/[c]atalina/{sub(/^  */,"", $0);print $1}'`
```

My csh/tcsh environment is acting up at the moment, so only lightly tested.

IHTH.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. 
Output of my grep is ` 1104 s002  S      6:25.87 /Library/Java/J...` So if I do this instead: set pnum = `ps ax | grep catalina | cut -d' ' -f 2 | cut -d' ' -f 1`, pnum now comes back

Comment: Thanks for the tips. 

Output of my grep is 

 1104 s002  S      6:25.87 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/stephenschultz/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache...

So if I do this instead of the command in my initial post

set pnum = `ps ax | grep catalina | cut -d' ' -f 2 | cut -d' ' -f  2

pnum comes back with

1104 8895

Where does the extra 8895 come from?

Comment: what happens if you get a PID that is only 3 places long? or 5, or 6? Also, you're creating a very "expensive" solution, in that you have 3 processes to "trim" out the value you need. The `awk` solution I include handles any size of a PID, and is only one process. But glad you're figuring stuff out on your own. Good luck.

Comment: "where does the extra 8895 come from". Again, I urge you to deconstruct your command and look at intermediate outputs. Are you saying that when you run just `ps ax | grep catalina` from the cmd-line you don't get 2 lines of output? You should. That is where `8895` is coming from and that is why I pointed you to a solution using `awk`, you can easily filter the unneeded lines. And that is why you had to use `|grep -v -grep` in your commented solution to nbari. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [pgrep](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pgrep):

```
set npid = `pgrep -n nginx`
echo $npid
```

The `-n` is to get the newest (most recently started) process

This also works (the method you are using):

```
set pnum = `ps ax | grep nginx | cut -d ' ' -f1`
```

What could be happening is that your process is not running or that there are some extra spaces at the beginning of the line, also probably you will have to do something like this:

```
set pnum = `ps ax | grep nginx | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f3`
```

Or use awk:

```
set pnum = `ps ax | awk '/nginx/{print $1}'`
```

Comment: This worked: set pnum = `ps ax | grep catalina | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f2`. Thanks!